# Comparing two network edge lists

Tags: python, awk

I have two lists- master.txt and a subset of it, child.txt. I want to print the edges in master.txt which are NOT there in child.txt

master.txt

```
A    B
B    C
D    F
```

child.txt

```
B    A
C    B
E    F
```

output:
   D   F

I have written a sample code

```
file1 = open("master.txt", "r")
file2 = open("child.txt", "r")
probe_id = file1.readlines()
loc_names = file2.readlines()`
#flag=0
for i in probe_id:
    i=i.rstrip()
    probe_info=i.split("\t")
    probe_info[0]=probe_info[0].strip()
    probe_info[1]=probe_info[1].strip()
    flag=0
    for j in loc_names:
        j=j.strip()
        loc_names=j.split("\t")
        loc_names[0]=loc_names[0].strip()
        loc_names[1]=loc_names[1].strip()  #throwing index out of range error
        if (probe_info[0]==loc_names[0] and probe_info[1]==loc_names[1]) or (probe_info[0]==loc_names[1] and probe_info[1]==loc_names[0]):
            flag=1
        if flag==0:
            print i
```

As of now, I am getting index out of range when I am splitting the smaller file. Kindly help. Also, if there is any other faster technique to do the same thing, pls let me know. Thanks

Comment: Edges are undirected?

Comment: Yes..they are undirected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly then all you need is:

```
$ awk '
    { edge=($1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1) }
    NR==FNR{ file1[edge]; next }
    !(edge in file1)
' child.txt master.txt
D    F
```

and if you ever wanted to find the edges in child that aren't in master you'd just flip the order of the input files:

```
$ awk '
    { edge=($1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1) }
    NR==FNR{ file1[edge]; next }
    !(edge in file1)
' master.txt child.txt
E    F
```

The above will be extremely fast since it's just doing a hash lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use python `dict` for fast lookups:

```
child = {}
with open('child.txt', 'r') as c:
    for line in c:
        p1, p2 = line.strip().split()
        child[p1] = p2
        child[p2] = p1


with open('master.txt', 'r') as m:
    for line in m:
        p1, p2 = line.strip().split()
        if child.get(p1) == p2:
            continue
        print(line)
```

---

Regarding your code, you are reassigning to `loc_names` to the pair `['E', 'F']`, so next iteration of the outer loop means inner loop over `loc_names` will set `j` will be `'E'`:

```
file1 = open("master.txt", "r")
file2 = open("child.txt", "r")
probe_id = file1.readlines()
loc_names = file2.readlines()`
#flag=0
for i in probe_id:
    i=i.rstrip()
    probe_info=i.split("\t")
    probe_info[0]=probe_info[0].strip()
    probe_info[1]=probe_info[1].strip()
    flag=0
    for j in loc_names: # j will be 'E' after second iteration of outer loop
        j=j.strip()
        loc_names=j.split("\t") 
        loc_names[0]=loc_names[0].strip()
        loc_names[1]=loc_names[1].strip()  # loc_names is ['E', 'F']
        if (probe_info[0]==loc_names[0] and probe_info[1]==loc_names[1]) or (probe_info[0]==loc_names[1] and probe_info[1]==loc_names[0]):
            flag=1
        if flag==0:
            print i
```

Comment: ah! now I got it. Thanks for showing me the python way !

Answer (score 1):

You can split the items in each line into `frozenset`s and put them into a `set` for each file, so that you can use `set.difference` to obtain what isn't in `child.txt` efficiently:

```
print(' '.join({frozenset(l.split()) for l in open("master.txt")} - {frozenset(l.split()) for l in open("child.txt")}))
```

Comment: Thanks, I have never used a frozenset before..it seems to be very useful

Answer (score 0):

This approach strips down each line so that just the nodes are remaining (e.g. `A    B` -> `AB`).  Then, since edges are undirected, just sort the pairs and then use a list comprehension to filter out the elements in `child`:

```
with open("master.txt", "r") as f:
    master = [''.join(sorted(x.strip().replace(" ", ""))) for x in f.readlines()]

with open("child.txt", "r") as f:
    child = [''.join(sorted(x.strip().replace(" ", ""))) for x in f.readlines()]

[x for x in master if x not in child] # ['DF']
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt, using `set` for sorting out duplicates:

```
with open('master.txt', 'r', newline='') as master_in, \
     open('child.txt', 'r', newline='') as child_in:

    seen = set(tuple(sorted(line.split())) for line in child_in)

    for line in master_in:
        if tuple(sorted(line.split())) not in seen:
            print(line)
```

Prints:

```
D    F
```